# creating application with entity framework and embbeded firebird

Tags: c#, entity-framework, firebird

**Information**
I'm using VS 2012 to develop a desktop WPF application (should run on win 7 and 8 later it will get a win 8 app),
with an embedded Firebird server,
and communicate with entity framework.
I'm using win 7/8 for development both with VS2012.

**Problem**
The application should work with embedded firebird at customer PC (no installation of FB).

I did Install the DDEX Provider for Visual Studio(3.0.0.0), as far it worked. I could add a new firebird connection (but getting error fbembed.dll not found). so i cant create the edmx file.

1. Do i need to install the firebird server(Superclassic/Classic or Superserver) or is it enough to just use Embedded server on my developer PC? if embedded is enough do i need to register the firebird client on gac?
2. as far i didn't found any useful information how to install and use it, and how to deploy it. do you guys have some good information links?

Answer (score 1):

For embedded server you just have to deploy the Firebird files along with your application and put the dll file somewhere accessible for it, for example, in the same folder.

The minimum files you have to deploy to get Firebird working is:

- FbEmbed.dll
- icudt30.dll
- icuin30.dll
- icuuc30.dll
- firebird.msg
- firebird.conf

This information, along with more usage instructions, is available in the file doc\README_embedded.txt.

> 1. USAGE
>
>    Just copy fbembed.dll, icudt30.dll, icuin30.dll and
>      icuuc30.dll into the directory with your application.
>      Then rename fbembed.dll to either fbclient.dll or
>      gds32.dll depending on your database connectivity software.
>      Then start your application and it will use the embedded
>      server as a client library and will be able to access
>      local datasases. You should also copy firebird.msg and
>      firebird.conf (if necessary) to the same directory.
>
>    If external libraries are required for your application,
>      then you should have them separately. Most probably, it
>      will be INTL support (fbintl.dll and fbintl.conf) or UDF
>      libraries. To be able to use them, you should place them
>      into the directory tree which emulates the Firebird server
>      one, i.e. has subdirectories like /intl or /udf: